# How to get from lidar coordinates to gps coordinates

Tags: slam, localization

I build a map from lidar slam `lego-loam`, which is a lidar odometer, and then I want to use this map by gps localization.

I know the map will have errors in some places, so the question is how do I get the ground truth of the lidar slam?
If the map and track are required to be overlapped, do I need to add GPS to lidar slam?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a [georeferencing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georeferencing) problem.  Where you have some map (your Lidar map), and want to register it (or align it) with another map (in this case GPS).

I would say, yes.  The best solution would just to be gather GPS data while you gather the Lidar map.

Without that, you probably have to do the alignment by hand.  You might be able to find some [GIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIS_file_formats) data for your area of interest.